# create JSON object starting from another JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to configure My API to be suitable with Chart.js

my API contains

```
{
    "Food": 900,
    "Shopping": 0,
    "Travel": 600,
    "Health": 0
}
```

it should be like

```
[
    {
      data:900,
      label: 'Food'
    },

    {
      data: 0,
      label: 'Shopping'
    },

    {
      data: 600,
      label: 'Travel'
    },
    {
      data: 0,
      label: 'Health'
    }
];
```

Comment: What have you attempted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just iterate through `Object.entries` and `push` each prop and label to an array:

```js
const data = { "Food": 900, "Shopping": 0, "Travel": 600, "Health": 0 };
let result = [];
Object.entries(data).forEach(prop => result.push({
  "data": prop[1],
  "label": prop[0]
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please explain @AymanSafi - I don't understand what you mean. Could you edit your question please? What would be an example of this JSON object you're  describing?

Answer (score 1):

Get an array of of your objects keys using `Object.Keys(yourObjectHere)`
Then you can loop through this array and use the keys to access the value stored for each key in your object. During the same iteration you can add on to your new object.
Ex:

```
var keys = Object.Keys(yourObjectHere)
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    var value = yourObjectHere[keys[i]];
    //add value and keys[i] to your new object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would help

```js
let origin = { "Food": 900, "Shopping": 0, "Travel": 600, "Health": 0 };

let newObject = Object.entries(origin).reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj.push({
    "label": item[0],
    "data": item[1]
  });
 return obj;
}, [])

console.log(newObject)
```

You can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DMolJ2FrNY) to have a better idea on how reduce works. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Its also possible to do it with `Object.keys`.
Here is an example

you can have a look at `Object.Keys` documentation here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

```js
var data = { "Food": 900, "Shopping": 0, "Travel": 600, "Health": 0 };
let result = [];
Object.keys(data).forEach(prop => 
result.push({
data: data[prop],
label: prop
}));

console.log(result);
```